# How do I navigate to the parent property (xmlproperty) - Codesmith

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, codesmith

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder xmlns="http://www.codesmithtools.com/purchaseorder">
  <ShipTo Name="Eric J. Smith">
    <Line1>123 Test Dr.</Line1>
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <State>TX</State>
    <Zip>75075</Zip>
  </ShipTo>
  <OrderDate>05-01-2003</OrderDate>
  <Items>
    <OrderedItem>
      <ItemName>Item #1</ItemName>
      <Description>Item #1 Description</Description>
      <UnitPrice>5.45</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <LineTotal>16.35</LineTotal>
    </OrderedItem>
    <OrderedItem>
      <ItemName>Item #2</ItemName>
      <Description>Item #2 Description</Description>
      <UnitPrice>12.75</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <LineTotal>102.00</LineTotal>
    </OrderedItem>
  </Items>
  <SubTotal>45.23</SubTotal>
  <ShipCost>5.23</ShipCost>
  <TotalCost>50.46</TotalCost>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I have the following codesmith template:

```
    <%@ XmlProperty Name="MyPurchaseOrder" Schema="PurchaseOrder.xsd" Default="SamplePurchaseOrder.xml" %>

    PurchaseOrder:
        Address:
            Name: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.Name %>
            Line1: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.Line1 %>
            City: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.City %>
            State: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.State %>
            Zip: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.Zip %>
        OrderDate: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.OrderDate %>
        Items:
            <% for (int i = 0; i < MyPurchaseOrder.Items.Count; i++) { %>
            <%= i %>:
                ItemName: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i].ItemName %>
//Here I need to traverse to the parent and print the City
                Description: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i].Description %>
                UnitPrice: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i].UnitPrice %>
                Quantity: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i].Quantity %>
                LineTotal: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i].LineTotal %>
            <% } %>
        SubTotal: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.SubTotal %>
        ShipCost: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipCost %>
        TotalCost: <%= MyPurchaseOrder.TotalCost %>
```

As I loop through the Items, I need to print the Address' city. In essence, how do I traverse to the parent (or a parent's parent)?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your example:

```
//Here I need to traverse to the parent and print the City
```

to this:

```
<%= MyPurchaseOrder.ShipTo.City %>
```

Since all of the 'paths' you are using are absolute (i.e. starting from `MyPurchaseOrder`), it should be possible to use an absolute path in this case (you don't need to navigate up to parent nodes).

Comment: This was an example I came up with that I now realize doesn't mimic the actual problem at hand. I do not have the absolute paths, so what I have is `var item = MyPurchaseOrder.Items[i];` and I am passing `item` to another method where I need to get the `City` property of the parent. Sorry for the confusion.